# dynamic_cast doesn't work across module boundaries on clang

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, llvm-clang

I am seeing a very strange failure that is very similar to the problem described in
[dynamic_cast on llvm clang compiler failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119136/dynamic-cast-on-llvm-clang-compiler-failing/14284207): `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` when I am trying to downcast from base type to derived type, for an object of derived type. In my case though `typeid` actually shows the same dynamic type.

Below is the debug function that I use to verify run-time types. It takes a pointer of `SrcType*` and tries to dynamically cast it to pointer of `DstType*`. If conversion fails, i.e. the returned pointer is `nullptr`, it prints an error message. `VERIFY()` macro checks if condition is true:

```
template<typename DstType, typename SrcType>
void CheckDynamicType( SrcType *pSrcPtr )
{
    VERIFY(dynamic_cast<DstType*> (pSrcPtr) != nullptr, 
           "Dynamic type cast failed. Src typeid: \'", typeid(*pSrcPtr).name(), 
           "\' Dst typeid: \'", typeid(DstType).name(), '\'');
}
```

And here is the output that I am getting:

```
Dynamic type cast failed. Src typeid: 'N8Diligent15RefCountersImplE' Dst typeid: 'N8Diligent15RefCountersImplE'
```

I am using clang compiler from Android ndk r16 toolchain. I am compiling with rtti flag. The same code works fine on gcc and msvc. 
Another bit of information: the code also works fine if I build it with `gnustl` runtime (I am not sure how gnu stl works with clang, but anyway).

UPDATE

After spending few more hours looking into the issue I found out that `dynamic_cast` fails when it is used on the object created in another module. 
From this 
[Using clang++, -fvisibility=hidden, and typeinfo, and type-erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496643/using-clang-fvisibility-hidden-and-typeinfo-and-type-erasure) and [this](http://www.russellmcc.com/posts/2013-08-03-rtti.html#foot1) posts it looks like `dynamic_cast` should work if the class is labeled with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` so that `typeid` structures from two modules will be merged. This, however does not help either and I am still seeing the issue.

Comment: Seems like caused by simple typographical error.

Comment: post a [mcve], please

Comment: @RustyX, why ? as far as I can tell, the semantics of CheckDynamicType is to **pass** if the pointer is either null or the dynamic cast succeeds...

Comment: Works for me with APP_PLATFORM=android-21, APP_STL=c++_static, APP_ABI=x86, on Mac. Is the pointer *expected* to print the same typeid, or this is an expected indication of compiler bug?

Comment: @RustyX sorry about confusing description. `VERIFY()` macro checks if expression is true and prints a debug message otherwise (I updated the question to make this clear). @Öö-Tiib so, it is not a typo. @RustyX `Dynamic type cast failed` is printed if it indeed failed (i.e. `dynamic_cast` returned `nullptr`), but then `typeid` shows the same type, which is my problem

Comment: @Alex-Cohn the macro only prints debug message if expression evaluates to `false`. So the meaning of the message it prints is that `dynamic_cast` returned `nullptr`, but `typeid` deduces that dynamic types actually match, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: I believe that you can deduce what the expected **typeid** should be. And if you check the same configuration on your side, this could be a step forward.

Comment: @Alex-Cohn The `typeid` printed by the macro is the correct and expected type id. So what happens is that I have `SrcType` and `DstType` for which `typeid(SrcType).name() == typeid(DstType).name()`, but `dynamic_cast<DstType*>(pSrcPtr) == nullptr`. I am using the most recent ndk version, but build for armv7

Comment: Please try [this](https://github.com/alexcohn/SO47322895). I used emulator at API=24

Comment: @Alex-Cohn thank you for looking into this. I found out that it fails because I use `dynamic_cast` on an object created in another module. This turned out to be a known issue and this post 
http://www.russellmcc.com/posts/2013-08-03-rtti.html#foot1
suggests that labeling class with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` should help, but I am still seeing the issue.

Comment: Do you use c++_shared or static?

Comment: @Alex-Cohn I tried both, but neither works. My understanding of the problem is that the compiler generates two identical `typeid` structures in two modules, and then only compares pointers, which are different. It is not related to static or dynamic version of run-time library. Labeling class visibility as default does not help for some reason either.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/533#issuecomment-335977747

Comment: @Alex-Cohn thank you for the link. This looks exactly like the problem I am seeing.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Should probably elevate that to an answer so it's more visible.

Answer (score -5):

If you’re using the stock system compiler there’s a near 0 chance dynamic_cast of the compiler isn’t working. This is tested and used extensively in everything from system software up.